# Program that generates singly linked list freezes

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program which among other things needs to generate a singly linked list...However after I create the list the program freezes(it doesn't give the segmentation fault error)...I tried to find out what the problem was so I commented the for loop in which the list is generated but the program kept freezing...

After i also commented the line of code where I allocate memory to the head of the list(which is a global pointer) the program worked , so it lead me to believe that something was wrong with the memory allocation for the head of the list(I still can't figure out what's wrong)

Could anyone shed some light on this problem?

```
    #include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct elem{
    int value;
    int worker;
    struct elem* next;
} ;

typedef struct elem Element;

Element* head;//the head of the list
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;//mutex for protecting the global counter variable

pthread_cond_t condition_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_rwlock_t rwlock_var;

sem_t semafor;


int counter;// the variable which wll count the nber of elements with the value less than 2`

int nrElements(Element* ptr);
void* thread_function(void*);


int main( int argc, char** argv)
{

    int nrEl,nrW; //nrEL- nr el of list, nrW - nr of workers
    int i;

    Element *tmp, *prev;
    pthread_t tid[ atoi(argv[2]) ];
    int orderNbers[atoi(argv[2])];//the order number for the threads

    printf("This is the main thread with thread no %u\n",pthread_self());
    /*create the read/write lock with default attributes(NULL) */
    pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock_var,NULL);

    sem_init(&semafor,0,3);  //initialize the semaphore
    nrEl = atoi(argv[1]);
    nrW = atoi(argv[2]);


    /* we now populate the worker field  */
    for (i=0; i<= nrW -1 ; i++) {
        orderNbers[i] = i;
    }



    /*allocate memory for the head(1st el of the list) */
    head  = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element));
    head->next = NULL;  
    /* generate the list with nrEl and
       assign random values( between 0-30) to its
       value field
    */
    tmp = head;

    for (i = 0; i <= nrEl -1 ; i++)
    {

        tmp->value = rand() % 30;
        /*at first we assign each element to a diff thread
            when the number of el > nr of threads
            we assign each element to the first threads     */
        if (i > nrW - 1){

            tmp->worker = i-nrW;
        }   
        else
        {
            tmp->worker = i;
        }


        printf("\nInitialize element number %d with value %d and worker %d",i,tmp->value,tmp->worker);
        /* if we reach the last element of the list
            we don't allocate memory for the next element
            so we assign it to NULL
            tmp , will now point to the last element of the list
        */
        if (i == nrEl -1 ){

            tmp->next = NULL;
            printf("\n%d\n ",i);
            break;

        }
        else {

        tmp->next  = (Element*) malloc(sizeof(Element) );
        tmp  = tmp->next;
        printf("\n%d\n",i);
        }
    }

    /* this is the part that doesnt execute anymore after the list creation*/    
    printf("\nCreating the threads");
    for (i=0; i<nrW ; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,thread_function,&orderNbers[i]);
    }
/* .... */
}
```

EDIT:I have edited the full problem since it appears that the lists are generated correctly

Comment: code looks fine. Are you sure that this program is showing the error? Which parameters are you using?

Comment: What is the expected output of the program?

Comment: Well, I think that this link list is causing the freezing, for example if I put a set of instructions after the for loop they don't execute...And the parameter nrEl is given at the command line and it is represents the length of the list

Comment: @Ganesh The part which generates the list is part of a larger program which uses threads..But after the list is generated the program doesn't get to the part where the threads are created hence I think that something is wrong with the list creation

Comment: @user3038668 can you reproduce the problem with *this* piece of code?

Comment: @user3038668.. I just compiled and ran your code with command line arguments of 5 10 and it worked perfectly fine. I get 5 prints which is the expected result along with a clean exit of the same. Hence, I am unable to correlate to your issue completely.

Comment: I have edited the problem and wrote the whole program until the creation of the threads since as you said the list don't appear to be the problem.

Comment: The code may not be hanging where you think it is. `printf` is buffered.  If you're using that as an indicator, it could be your code is hanging somewhere in the code you omitted.